# Excluding a pod from service in statefulset Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a statefulset with 5 replica. This means I have pods with name pod-0 .. pod-4.

I want to create 2 service.

1. A service that only routes the request to pod-0 ( this is my edit server ) : I know I can achieve this by "statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=pod-0"  in the service selector. This is fine.
2. A service that routes the request to all remaining nodes excluding pod-0( even if the application scales up and add more instances those new instances needs to be mapped to this service) : I am unable to achieve this.

Any idea on how to achieve the 2nd service ??

Since it is deployed via 1 stateful manifest file , all pods are having same label .

Comment: will this [workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44103#issuecomment-326851272) help you somehow? The main idea is to additionally add labels to use them in future  with service, etc (even if pods were restated)

Comment: Hi @Vitalii . Thanks for the info . I followed this approach.

1. Created Role + role binding + service account which have rights to update the label.
2. At the end of the script that I execute using Docker file [CMD] , I installed kubectl and then executed 

kubectl label pod ${HOSTNAME} pod-type=${POD_TYPE} --server=https://kubernetes.default --token=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token) --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -n ${POD_NAMESPACE}

Above env variables I am passing in the statefulsets. It served my purpose.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Please post you comment as an answer for future researchers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the info . I followed this approach.

1. Created Role + role binding + service account which have rights to update the label.
2. At the end of the script that I execute using Docker file [CMD] , I installed kubectl and then executed
   *kubectl label pod ${HOSTNAME} pod-type=${POD_TYPE} --server=kubernetes.default --token=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token) --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -n ${POD_NAMESPACE}*

Above env variables I am passing in the statefulsets. It served my purpose.